# Let $p,q$ be primes and $|G|=p^3q^3$ for an abelian group $G$. Prove that there exists a subgroup $H$ of order $pq^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $p,q$ be primes and $|G|=p^3q^3$ for an abelian group $G$. Prove that there exists a subgroup $H$ of order $pq^3$.

The hint tells I can use Cauchy, Sylow and Factor Theorem, so that there is a subgroup $H^{´}$, $H^{´´}$ by Sylow's theorem which satisfies $|H'| \mid |G|$ and $|H''| \mid |G|$ with order $p^3$ and $q^3$, respectively. But then I'm stuck.

I've been trying some ideas by looking into  $|G| = |H|\times i_G(H)$ where maybe $ i_G(H)= p^2$ by Lagrange's theorem. Also, trying to make use of the set generated by $x \in G$ due to $G$ is abelian by Cauchy's theorem.

Any idea on how to proceed? Thank you very much for your reading

Comment: For an *abelian* group $G$ you surely don't need Sylow theory to build a proof.  However the word "abelian" only appears in the title and in passing near the finish of your post.  It's recommended to give a full problem statement in the body of your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_q$ be a $q$-Sylow of $G$, by Cauchy theorem there exists $g\in G$ of order $p$. Since $G$ is abelian, all its subgroups are normal, therefore $S_q\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $|S_q\cap\langle g\rangle|$ divides $|S_q|=q^3$ and $|\langle g\rangle|=p$, then $S_q\cap\langle g\rangle=\{e\}$, therefore using the second isomorphism theorem, $|S_p\langle g\rangle|=q^3p$ and you're done.

Answer (score -3):

Converse of Lagrange’s Theorem is true for abelian groups. Hence for every divisor of the order of G we have subgroups. Hence we are done.